# matplotlib, nested axes position transformation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add a big plotting area (axes), and then, a small plotting area (axes) **nested inside** :

```
big = BigArea(figure, bbox=Bbox([[0.1, 0.2], [0.9, 0.8]]), xlim=(0, 6), ylim=(1, 5))
small = big.add_area(bbox=Bbox([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
```

[image: Nested axes]

The big area coordinates are contained **inside the figure limits** : Bbox([[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]])

The small area coordinates are contained **inside the big area limits** : Bbox([[0.0, 1.0], [6.0, 5.0]])

I'd like to handle the coordinates with matplotlib transformations, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly. This is my implementation :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox, BboxTransformTo

class BigArea:
    def __init__(self, figure, bbox, xlim, ylim):
        ax = figure.add_axes(bbox)
        ax.set_xlim(xlim)
        ax.set_ylim(ylim)
        self._figure = figure
        self._bbox = bbox
        self._ax = ax

    def add_area(self, bbox):
        ax = self._ax
        t = ax.transLimits + BboxTransformTo(self._bbox)
        bbox2 = bbox.transformed(t)
        figure = self._figure
        small = figure.add_axes(bbox2)
        return small

figure = plt.figure()
big = BigArea(figure, bbox=Bbox([[0.1, 0.2], [0.9, 0.8]]), xlim=(0, 6), ylim=(1, 5))
small = big.add_area(bbox=Bbox([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))

# plt.savefig('nested_axes_position_transformation.png')
plt.show()
```

Is it the right way to do it ? Is there a better way ? A shorter way ?

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to relate the scales/extents of the two axes.  If so, you might have a look at inset axes in `axes_grid1`: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#insetlocator  On the other hand, if you just need to know "given screen position x,y, what's the data coordinates position in either/both axes", then that's overkill. Use `ax.transData.inverted()` instead.